# what's a good feedback to user while a Database script is running

Tags: c#, winforms

C# WinForms: In my application when user clicks on a toolbar button, I go run a SQL script on the back-end which takes like 2 minutes to run.. which is fine :) that's how much it really will take to run. But while this script is running I was thinking of showing some feedback to the user, If I can do something quick and easy that main form is still responsive while script is running then even better, but not really necessary..I am mostly thinking of showing some visual feedback to the user that shows the script is running...

What do you suggest? a quick and dirty approach is fine.

Comment: *"Hang on to your hat!"* never fails me.

Comment: Isn't there a mouse icon with an arrow and a little hourglass on it for this sort of thing?

Comment: @JackT.Colton : Yeah...want something more pretty. !

Comment: A rainbow colored spinney wheel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [BackGroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class. You can run your sql query in the background while the UI stays responsive to the user. For simple operations, it could be easily implemented taking away the complexities associated with threading operations. You can get feedback from the backgroundworker when it has completed running.